# How to use case statement based on for loop in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

My source data is something like this - see the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gg5B.png)

Now i am trying to calculate START_DATE_ID based on OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM for each unique combination of PORTFOLIO_GROUP,PORTFOLIO_REGION,LIMIT_NAME. For this i am using this case statement in select statement

```
CASE 
OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM = 0 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q')
OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM = 1 THEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'),3)
OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM = 2 THEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'),6) -- 6 is multiple of 3 and so on
OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM = 3 THEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'),9)
OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM = 4 THEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'),12)
OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM = 5 THEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'),15)
END AS START_DATE_ID
```

now my problem is that value of OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM is not limited to 5 for each combination of PORTFOLIO_GROUP,PORTFOLIO_REGION,LIMIT_NAME.

So how to run this case statement like for 0..max(OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM) for each combination of PORTFOLIO_GROUP,PORTFOLIO_REGION,LIMIT_NAME

Comment: Something like `ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'), OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM * 3)`? (untested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second parameter to `ADD_MONTHS` is always  `3*OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM`  ,then you may use

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'),3*OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM) AS START_DATE_ID
    FROM Yourtable;
```

Or else use,

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'),b.months_to_add) AS START_DATE_ID
        FROM Yourtable a,
(
  select DISTINCT OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM ,months_to_add FROM Yourtable 
) b WHERE 
a.OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM = b.OFFSET_PERIOD_FROM;
```